# how to connect multiple kvm/qemu VM guests in to a subnet

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I want to setup a simple subnetwork of KVM/QEMU guest VMs living on a single host (Fedora 19) for testing purposes. The subnet would contain 3 servers:

## 1 Debian 6.x

eth0
    ip: 10.0.0.7
eth1
    ip: 10.0.2.1

## 2 Debian 7.x

eth0
    ip: 10.0.2.2

## 2 CentOS 6.x

eth0
    ip: 10.0.2.3

and (possibly) multiple clients.

The idea is to simulate a subnet where only one VM (#1 from the above) is connected to WAN network and serves as a gateway/router for the rest.

I'm currently experimenting with a setup based on the one described here:

http://csortu.blogspot.com/2009/12/building-virtual-network-with-qemu.html

But, for the moment, can't seem to provide other VMs besides #1 with WAN connectivity.

I have two qestions:
1. Is there an easier solution?
2. (if not) how can I make other VMs connect with the outside world using VM #1 as gateway.

P.s. I should probably mention, that all VMs connect with each other, but WAN access is available only on #1.

EDIT: As requested, here is the complete network config.

HOST: Fedora 19 x86-64 directly connected to my home router (10.0.0.1) on 10.0.0/24 network (only print relevant interfaces)

```
3: wlp12s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 0c:60:76:64:c5:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.3/28 brd 10.0.0.15 scope global wlp12s0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::e60:76ff:fe64:c59d/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
link/ether 2e:47:f7:fc:f2:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

VMs:

## 1 - Debian 6 amd64 with two NICs configured (one for access to my home network via the HOST, and the second for internal, VM-only 10.0.2/24 subnet)

Here is the startup command (I've changed the default QEMU user network config to reflect my home network and redirected HOST port 2222 to access port 22-ssh on the GUEST)

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -enable-kvm --name Debian6-amd64 -hda VMs/Debian6/sda.img -hdb VMs/Debian6/sdb.img -net nic,vlan=1 -net user,vlan=1,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22,net=10.0.0.0/24,dhcpstart=10.0.0.7 -net nic,vlan=2,macaddr=52:54:00:00:02:01 -net socket,vlan=2,listen=localhost:1234 -m 512 -boot c -nographic
```

and here are the interface configs:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:12:34:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.7/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:00:02:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.1/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth1
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe00:201/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## 2 - Debian 7 amd64 with one NIC configured (internal 10.0.2/24 subnet)

The startup command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -enable-kvm --name Debian7-amd64 -hda VMs/Debian7/sda.img -hdb VMs/Debian7/sdb.img -net nic,vlan=2,macaddr=52:54:00:00:02:02 -net socket,vlan=2,connect=localhost:1234 -m 512 -boot c -nographic
```

and the interface config

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:00:02:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.2/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe00:202/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## 3 - CentOS 6 x86-64 with one NIC configured (internal 10.0.2/24 subnet)

The startup command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -enable-kvm --name CentOS6-x86_64 -hda VMs/CentOS6/sda.img -hdb VMs/CentOS6/sdb.img -net nic,vlan=2,macaddr=52:54:00:00:02:03 -net socket,vlan=2,connect=localhost:1234 -m 512 -boot c -nographic
```

and the interface config

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:00:02:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.3/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe00:203/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: And how did you set up the networking?

Comment: Similar to the setup described in the link I provided. Used 2x NICs with separate QEMU "VLANs" on VM #1 and 1x NIC with the second QEMU "VLAN" only on other VMs.

Comment: Just providing a link is not going to work. You need to describe it exactly as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Debian6 VM configured to forward IP packets ?

Have you configured default routes on the other 2 VMs pointing to the VM Debian 6 ?

If yes, could you try changing the internal lan to another major subnet other than 10.x.x.x, i.e. 192.168.1.x/24 ?

After you use the new internal subnet, you will need to configure a route to the internal subnet 192.168.1.x on your internet router pointing to the Debian6 VM.